# How do I know what's in my jQuery UI custom build?

Tags: jquery-ui

I'd like to upgrade my jQuery UI version due to an annoying slider bug found in older versions.

My problem is that I'm using a custom jQuery UI build, with an inherited codebase. The current jquery-ui.min.js is about 260k, so I really don't want to download the whole thing at 2 megs zipped!! Is there any way to easily figure out exactly what I'm using so I can upgrade only the relevant bits?

Comment: It should list which modules are included as a comment at the top, unless someone took it out.  If they took out the comment, do you have the non-min version?  They probably wouldn't have taken out the comment on that one.

Comment: @Mystere-man It's definitely not in the top comments, they're pretty sparse, and there's no unminified file I can see. I guess I might just have to bite the bullet and guess, then test thoroughly.